# Возможно ли программно изменить качество url-потока в приложении?

Tags: java, android, аудио, exoplayer

В приложение (плеер) приходит ссылка на аудио поток, битрейт которого 320kbps.

Возможно ли какими-либо средствами (библиотеками и т.д) программно изменить качество на выходе? То есть уменьшить до 192kbps или 128kbps например?

Или только искать ссылку на url-поток соответствующего качества (64kbps, 128kbps и т.д..) ?

**P.S:** в приложении использую библиотеку ExoPlayer для воспроизведения. Заранее благодарю, за все возможные варианты, ответы или предложения!

Comment: Как вариант, вы можете выкачивать поток, если это файл, если просто поток, то просто сжимать. Библиотеки должны быть, но также можно собственными ByteStream'ами

Comment: А цель какая? Если экономия трафика, то говорить даже не о чем. Чтобы уменьшить качество, надо сначала получить в исходном, и вопрос не имеет смысла

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий, то есть с ваших слов получается что-то вроде такой схемы: Мы получаем поток 320kbps, режем (жмем) его качество до 128kbps, но трафика кушаем всё равно доступной для потока 320kbps ? В результате чего у нас получается "имитация экономии трафика" ?

Comment: Именно так - технически мы не можем "пропускать" байты сетевого потока и даже если бы могли, то на выходе получили бы бред из-за недостающей информации для раскодирования.